# Why is Visual C++ 2010 complaining about 'Using uninitialized memory'?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've got a function that takes a pointer to a buffer, and the size of that buffer (via a pointer). If the buffer's not big enough, it returns an error value and sets the required length in the out-param:

```
// FillBuffer is defined in another compilation unit (OBJ file).
// Whole program optimization is off.
int FillBuffer(__int_bcount_opt(*pcb) char *buffer, size_t *pcb);
```

I call it like this:

```
size_t cb = 12;
char *p = (char *)malloc(cb);
if (!p)
    return ENOMEM;

int result;
for (;;)
{
    result = FillBuffer(p, &cb);
    if (result == ENOBUFS)
    {
        char *q = (char *)realloc(p, cb);
        if (!q)
        {
            free(p);
            return ENOMEM;
        }

        p = q;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Visual C++ 2010 (with code analysis cranked to the max) complains with `'warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'p': Lines: ...'`. It reports line numbers covering pretty much the entire function.

Visual C++ 2008 doesn't. As far as I can tell, this code's OK. What am I missing? Or what is VC2010 missing?

Comment: What line is the warning attributed to?

Comment: This is what I got when I tried it: d:\testpro\sss\sss\sss.cpp(27): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'p': Lines: 13, 14, 16, 21, 22, 24, 25, 31, 21, 22, 24, 25, 31, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27    Basically all the lines in the function

Comment: Hmm, I'm stumped then. My guess is VC++'s static analysis doesn't know about `realloc()`'s (well-defined) behaviour when `p` is NULL (i.e. if the original `malloc()` failed).  Or does `FillBuffer()` itself misbehave in this case? In which case VC++ is on the ball?

Comment: FillBuffer is in a separate OBJ file, so VC++ has no way of knowing what it does other than the prototype. Whole program optimization is off.

Comment: Oh, and checking the result of malloc doesn't fix it either. Updated the question slightly.

Comment: A related question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513003/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to be a bug in Visual Studio 2010. Wrapping `malloc` removes the warning, as in the following tested code:

```
char * mymalloc(int i)  
{  
    return (char *) malloc(i);  
}

// ...

void *r = mymalloc(cb);

char *p;

p = (char *) malloc(cb);
```

Comment: You are right. My mistake, it needs to be char *p = NULL to make the warnings go away. (Should probably down vote myself). (I think I did a rebuild and not an analyse by mistake)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I've raised a bug on Connect.

Comment: If you are not happy with your own answer you can edit or remove it and make it easier for later visitors (make sure they understand the answer is not such even if they don't go into comments)

Answer (score -1):

You did not check if the first malloc() is ok. This leads to the warning.

Comment: malloc will alwavs return something so p will always get a value. I don't think this is the issue

Comment: FillBuffer accepts NULL, and puts the appropriate required size in the out-param.