# Why is VS2013 complaining about "using uninitialized memory"?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2013

I have a code that goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *a;
    char *b;
    int c;
} my_type;

void free_my_type(my_type *p) {
    if (p) {
        if (p->a) free(p->a);  // line 12
        if (p->b) free(p->b);  // line 13
        free(p);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    my_type *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));

    p->a = malloc(10);
    p->b = malloc(10);
    p->c = 10;

    free_my_type(p);

    return 0;
}
```

VS's Code Analysis is complaining that I am:

```
"C6001 Using uninitialized memory '*p'"

        '*p' is not initialized                             12
        Skip this branch, (assume 'p->b' is false)          13
        '*p' is used, but may not have been initialized     13
```

I mean, it's a pointer and I'm checking to see if it is `NULL`. How will I ever know if *p is initialized?

Oddly enough, if there's only 1 other pointer inside the struct -- only `char *a`, for example -- the warning doesn't trigger. It also doesn't show up if I do `free(p->b)` before `free(p->a)` (swap lines 12 and 13).

Comment: This code looks fine to me, perhaps the code analysis is bugged.

Comment: `if ( p->a )` is redundant as `free` performs this check itself

Comment: OOC, does converting to `my_type *p = calloc(1, sizeof(*p));` stop the warning? It shouldn't matter, but I wonder if it would suppress the warning. It's possible it's assuming exception raising behaviors or something, where not all the pointers would be initialized under certain conditions (not evident in the code as written, but small changes, like making allocation of `p->b` contingent on successful allocation of `p->a`) could trigger that.

Comment: @M.M: didn't know that, thanks :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger, it doesn't suppress the warning. Removing the `if (p->a)` and `if (p->b)` does, tho. Weird.

Comment: @sthiago Try passing address of `p` to your function with changing function parameter type to `**p`.

Comment: @ameyCU I tried that. It complains about `'**p'` instead of `'*p'`

Comment: @ameyCU: Why would you think that is meaningful/helpful?

Comment: You really should be checking to make sure the first `malloc` call didn't return `NULL`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, the sample code is just to illustrate the issue

Comment: Try passing my_type instead of *p in the malloc?

Comment: I am getting completely different warnings, triggered by not testing if malloc() failed.  Be sure to apply the VS2013 updates, they had lots of code analysis fixes.

Comment: @Hans Passant, my visual studio 2013 ultimate is at update 5 (latest), vs2015 at latest too, even with that, I have these warning C6001 and C6011 warnings

Comment: There is a solution for the C6011 warning by wraping the malloc and adding if(p) just before the instruction p->a = malloc(10); for example. but the C6001 still a strange output by the analyzer

Comment: Yeah, I incluced just enough code to produce C6001. C6011 is trivial to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the analyzer tool of visual studio 2013

as explained here:

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/analyze-for-visual-studiothe-ugly-part-1/

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/analyze-for-visual-studiothe-ugly-part-2/

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/analyze-for-visual-studiothe-ugly-part-3-false-positives/

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/analyze-for-visual-studiothe-ugly-part-4-false-negatives/

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/analyze-for-visual-studio-the-ugly-part-5/

as an update in the part 5, we can read this:

> **Update: Luckily VC++ 2013 has solved many of these issues, but the problems with __analysis_assume remain.**

So even if they solved many of theses warning issues with newest visual studio versions, still some bugs occurs in the analyzer tool.

Test with VS2015 Enterprise: gives the same problem

[image]

Comment: I removed the ifs (now that I know that free does the checking itself) and it suppressed the warning for this specific case. There are other cases of false positives, tho.